# Sphinx automodule runs my code

Tags: python-sphinx

If I include the following document

```
The xxx API reference
===============================

.. automodule:: sphinx_test
   :members:
```

in my Sphinx documentation it runs the module sphinx_test.py every time I 'make html'

Is this normal? Is there a flag somewhere to turn off this behaviour that I'm missing?

Comment: Your module needs an execution guard like `if __name__ == "__main__": main()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, it was because I was running a wxPython app and my

```
screen_app = wx.App()
main_frame = MainFrame()
screen_app.MainLoop()
```

code was not protected by

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

Thanks Paebbels for the hint